# How to get equal number of elements after range division leaving a remainder

Tags: c, multithreading, formula, division

I know the title is not the best description but it was the best I could do . 
 Long story sort, I am trying to get a range of numbers, 
lets say for the example : 
MIN: 0 and MAX: 10 ,
so the range would be 10 .
 
I want to divide the range in n fields (The user gives this this input, so it is variable) and then create n threads-children , using fork() , where each one will get its own sub-range of these numbers and execute some code using these numbers , actually its going to check if this number is a prime number or not.
So my problem is that I can't think of a formula to write so that the numbers will be equally split.

I tried:

```cpp
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        //fork()
        int temp = MIN + (i*(RANGE/n));
        for(int a =; a< temp +(RANGE/n)+1; a++){
            //check if prime
            //other actions
         }
     }
```

But I know this will not work correctly because if we have 3 threads(n),it is going to check the ranges (0,3) , (3,6) , (6,9) because the

> (RANGE/n) gives 3

That means that the last number , in this example the 10, will never be checked in cases where the division of the RANGE from the N number of children leave a remain.
Is there any smart way to split the range and check all the numbers by different number of processes each time ? 
 thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get equal number of elements after range division leaving a remainder

Various approaches.

A key issues is if the `0` and `10` are both included in the integer range:  Is it `[0... 10]` or `[0... 10)` or ...?  Notice the `]` or `)`?  Let us assume the lists end-points are included and `[0... 10]` is  11 different integer values.

Note: There are extremes such as having 11 numbers divided into 12 groups.

The below forms the sub-range from the first `1/n` part of the range, then the  `1/(n-1)` part of the remaining range, etc.

```
void range(int n, int inclusive_min, int inclusive_max) {
  printf("Range [%d %d] / %d\n", inclusive_min, inclusive_max, n);
  for(int i = n; i > 0 && inclusive_min <= inclusive_max; i--) {
    int range = 1 + inclusive_max - inclusive_min;
    int sub_range = range/i;
    if (sub_range == 0) sub_range = 1;
    printf("Sub range [%d %d]\n", inclusive_min, inclusive_min + sub_range - 1);
    inclusive_min += sub_range;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  range(3, 0, 10);
  range(2, 0, 10);
  range(5, 0, 10);
  range(3, 0, 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Range [0 10] / 3
Sub range [0 2]
Sub range [3 6]
Sub range [7 10]
Range [0 10] / 2
Sub range [0 4]
Sub range [5 10]
Range [0 10] / 5
Sub range [0 1]
Sub range [2 3]
Sub range [4 5]
Sub range [6 7]
Sub range [8 10]
Range [0 1] / 3
Sub range [0 0]
Sub range [1 1]
```

---

A more elegant solution, akin to [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)

```
void range(int n, int inclusive_min, int inclusive_max) {
  printf("Range [%d %d] / %d\n", inclusive_min, inclusive_max, n);
  int range = 1 + inclusive_max - inclusive_min;
  int sub_range = range / n;
  int sub_range_res = range % n;
  int p = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int next = inclusive_min + sub_range;
    p += sub_range_res;
    if (2 * p >= n) {  // like p >= n/2 without integer truncation.
      p -= n;
      next++;
    }
    if (next > inclusive_min) {
      printf("Sub range %d:[%d %d]\n", i, inclusive_min, next - 1);
    }
    inclusive_min = next;
  }
}
```

Output

```
Range [0 10] / 3
Sub range 0:[0 3]
Sub range 1:[4 6]
Sub range 2:[7 10]
Range [0 10] / 2
Sub range 0:[0 5]
Sub range 1:[6 10]
Range [0 10] / 5
Sub range 0:[0 1]
Sub range 1:[2 3]
Sub range 2:[4 6]
Sub range 3:[7 8]
Sub range 4:[9 10]
Range [0 1] / 3
Sub range 0:[0 0]
Sub range 2:[1 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your task is to verify if a number is prime, it is convenient that the larger numbers are in smaller groups (since it is more difficult to verify that they are prime numbers).

You could use a policy, started by MAX. Then create the following interval: {MAX-1, MAX-2} for example (and so on) until you have the number of required ranges.